# Low hot water pressure at kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing

Low hot water pressure at kitchen faucet and first floor bathroom faucets.  Small ba thromm on first floor and upstairs faucets oressure is good.  I replaced the shut valve on kitchen faucet,  thinking it may be plugged, but that did;t make any difference.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

You may have sediment debris in the aerator or the valve assembly. Every few month we have to pull our aerators out and clean them. We have pretty hard water here. When you replace or turn off/on your shut off valves, you introduce debris into the system. Debris like built-up sediment, calcium, etc. This dislodges and makes its way to the tap, plugging small areas along the way.